# Filter view results by "created"/"authored on" date - shows all content regardless of post date

Tags: views, datetime

I've been throwing myself at this for a while, apologies if I've missed anything stupidly obvious.

I'm trying to create a table of statistics for content submitted by all users (using Views Aggregator Plus to do the number crunching) and for the most part, it works fine. If I only wanted to show results from all time, it would be perfect.

However, I would like to show the same table but only aggregating content from the past 30 days -- and this is where it gets tricky.

No matter how I configure the filter, if I'm using any of the default content fields (created, updated, etc) with the default date filter options of *date in machine readable time* or *offset from current time*, it returns all results.

[image: Date filter settings]

I have the SQL query visible so I can see what's going on, and it doesn't appear to be adding the date filter to the query *at all*.

This is my basic query:

```
SELECT node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('type1', 'type2'))
```

It doesn't change when I adjust the filter options above.

However, if I use the "Date in YYYY format", which is a filter from a contrib module, it shows in the query and filters like it should:

```
SELECT node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('type1', 'type2')) AND ((YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(node_field_data.created)) >= 2021))
```

The issue doesn't seem to happen with custom date fields. I'm wondering if there's something kooky going on in how Views is handling the dates that are created by the system? When I look at the form display for the content, it shows them as using different "widgets".

Fields created by the system use "Datetime Timestamp", where custom date fields use "Date and Time".

It seeems odd that custom date fields filter beautifully, but default ones don't. And double weird that I would need a contrib module to make use of that information.

I'm running Drupal 8.9.1, everything is up to date. I've tried running from a clean install with the same results. If I run the content through Search API and include "authored on" as an indexed field, the date filtering works *but* the table aggregation doesn't sort properly.

How do I get Views to recognise and use that data so that I can filter my results down to content posted in X amount of days? Or failing that, what other steps could I take to try and work out where the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is interesting. When I test this on one of my views it works as expected. If you add this same filter to the Recent Content view (`/admin/structure/views/view/content_recent`), does it work there? Does this happen if you disable aggregation? What are you using aggregation for?

Comment: It's so weird, right? It does the same thing on the content_recent view. It does it on new views that haven't got aggregation yet. 

All I need to do to replicate the issue is create a new view showing all published content, set it to show all items (because I want them limited by date not count) and the date filter doesn't work.

Comment: Query from the content_recent view:

SELECT node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid, users_field_data_node_field_data.uid AS users_field_data_node_field_data_uid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
INNER JOIN {users_field_data} users_field_data_node_field_data ON node_field_data.uid = users_field_data_node_field_data.uid
WHERE ((node_field_data.status = 1 OR (node_field_data.uid = 1 AND 1 <> 0 AND 1 = 1) OR 1 = 1 OR 1 = 1)) AND (node_field_data.type IN ('type1', 'type2'))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC

Comment: Somehow I fixed this. No idea how, but it's working now.